# How to identify if a contact id is associated with an administrator role?

Tags: contacts, roles

I need to write a code to identify if a contact id is associated with an administrator role in my civiCRM extension and it needs to be platform independent.
How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in a platform-independent way since "admin role" means different things in different CMS's. What you can do that is platform-independent is check specific CiviCRM permissions, e.g. `CRM_Core_Permission::check('administer CiviCRM', $contact_id)`

You can leave out $contact_id to check for the currently logged-in user.